# How to integrate the following code into website

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have this .jsx file that i want to integrate into my website, So I was testing it out on a single page site as demo, But nothing's showing up...can anyone help me with the steps about how I can integrate it into my site? I am also attaching the .CSS file . I am trying to create a floating widget, but I can somehow use it in my site. Any idea?

```
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";

export default function FloatingIcons() {
  function handleActiveClass() {
    document.getElementById("circularMenu").classList.toggle("active");
  }
  return (
    <div id="circularMenu" className="circular-menu">
      <a className="floating-btn" onClick={handleActiveClass}>
        <i class="fa fa-question" style={{ fontSize: "30px" }} />
      </a>
      <menu className="items-wrapper">
        <a href="/" className="menu-item">
          <i className="fa fa-comments" />
        </a>
        <a href="/" className="menu-item">
          <i className="fa fa-bug" />
        </a>
        <a href="/" className="menu-item">
          <i className="fa fa-search" />
        </a>
      </menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The CSS File:

```
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css";

.circular-menu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1em;
  right: 1em;
}

.circular-menu .floating-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 3.5em;
  height: 3.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: hsl(4, 98%, 60%);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.26);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 4.1;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
}

.circular-menu .floating-btn i {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.circular-menu:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  width: 3.5em;
  height: 3.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.circular-menu.active:after {
  transform: scale3d(5.5, 5.5, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, 1.55, 0.265, 1);
}

.circular-menu .items-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.circular-menu .menu-item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.2em;
  right: 0.2em;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3;
  background-color: #008cff;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, background 0.2s ease;
}

.circular-menu .menu-item:hover {
  background-color: #2b80c5;
}

.circular-menu.active .menu-item {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.circular-menu.active .menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate3d(-0.8em, -6.5em, 0);
}

.circular-menu.active .menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate3d(-4.5em, -4em, 0);
}

.circular-menu.active .menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate3d(-5.5em, 0.3em, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you have to change your CSS `@import` statement to

```
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css");
```

to make it work inside `./index.css` with JS `import "./index.css";`

Next is that it looks as if you have built on the content of an `App.js` file and now try to use it as an `index.js`? Keeping separate App.js and unchanged index.js (from create react app, I suppose) would give you the required `ReactDOM.render` via index.js, otherwise copy the first two and the last line of index.js as the first two and the last line to your JSX, i.e.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

at start and

```
ReactDOM.render(<FloatingIcons />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

at end, replacing default **App** in the last line by your **FloatingIcons** and supposing that you *have* an element with id "root" in your HTML. Note that you can keep your "import React" line, "import" would recognize that "React" is already loaded, but it should be imported before "ReactDOM" that relies on it.